# "Every element of Sym$(n)$ has order at most $n$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I was doing mini-test involving a True/False section and came across the following statement.

> Every element of $Sym(n)$ has order at most $n$

I admit I had gotten this incorrect as I had thought that the statement is true, but the answer was that the statement is false.

However, I am having trouble seeing a counter example, and I would appreciate one for the sake of understanding symmetric groups further.

Comment: what is $n$ and what is Sym$(n)$

Comment: Sym$(n)$ is the symmetric group of $n$ elements. Apologies for the lack of clarification, I had thought this was universal notation.

Comment: What's the order of $(123)(45)$?

Comment: Well that was quick. Thank you for that example, I'm a little embarrassed.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A000793 for this interesting sequence which begins 1,2,3,4,6,6,12

Answer (score 3):

In the future it will be worthwhile for you to know how to compute the order of an element of $\mathrm{Sym}(n)$, so I will detail it here.

Recall that every permutation is a product of disjoint cycles, for example $\sigma=35412$ is $(134)(25)$. Disjoint cycles commute with each other, so exponentiating a permutation amounts to raising each disjoint cycle in a decomposition to the same power. You can verify that $\sigma^3=(134)^3(25)^3=(25)$.

A cycle of length $k$, say $(i_1i_2i_3\cdots i_k)$, has order exactly $k$, and the order of a permutation will be the smallest number that is divisible by the orders of all of the cycles, in other words their least common multiple. So the order of $\sigma$ is $\mathrm{lcm}(2,3)=6$, which is small enough to verify manually.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote but it seems to me that $\sigma = (35412) \neq (134)(25)$. (just calculate the image of $3$ to see this)

Comment: @learner  $35412 \neq (35412)$. It's one-line notation. $\sigma(1)=3$, $\sigma(2)=5$, etc.

Comment: I see. Do you know that the asker (and the downvoter?) know this notation? It seems weird to me to use more than one notation for the same thing in a post as short as this. But that's just me of course.

Comment: @learner ...but it's a permutation.  One line notation is the usual way to express them.